# Root partition full? CentOS

Tags: centos, partition

I'm running CentOS 5.4 and my **/** is full. I wanted to install gparted but in order to do that I must install Priorities and it's when I get an error saying **/** is full so I can't go forward.

Here's some output:

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30394 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        2611    20972826   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            2612        3251     5140800   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3            3252       30394   218026147+  83  Linux
```

**df**

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             20315812  19365152         0 100% /
/dev/sda3            211196248  49228164 151066780  25% /home
tmpfs                  1552844         0   1552844   0% /dev/shm
```

I'm not using LVM.
Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a bootable disc like RIP (rescue is possible) Linux and use gParted on that?

Make sure you have a decent backup of your data first. Never play with partition information on production systems with important data without known good backups unless you're ready to possibly lose data (although RIP linux discs also have testdisk to try retrieving data from damaged partitions if something does go wrong...)

Comment: I don't have physical access to the server, so I must rely on cli only.

Comment: Changing partition information from remote CLI only? You're brave...

Comment: I'd probably next look at your /var/logs directory and see what can be cleaned from there, then see if there's anything that is cached in your installation system for Centos that can be cleaned out (I don't know the equivalent to Ubuntu's "apt-get autoclean" in CentOS off the top of my head).

Comment: If enough space is freed doing that you should be okay to try the very dangerous manipulation of the partition tables from remote. If not, you might need to look at creating symbolic links from some directories to a temporary storage space in /home. Need to be careful of services that are accessing open files, though, as open file handles will not let go of open file space even if the files look like they're gone. Processes also don't like having their logs or data files yoinked out from under them, so exit running apps/daemons first.

Comment: Turns out I managed to free 10 gigs that were being occupied by a virtual box vdi virtual disk.

Answer (score 1):

move some database files /var/lib/mysql to your home partition. First stop the mysql service before doing that. Then enlarge the disk, and place the files back. That should work perfect. Done that many times.